# Minimizing $f(t,s) = a \cos(t) + b \cos(s) + c \cos(t - s) $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to minimize

$$ f(t, s) = a \cos(t) + b \cos(s) + c \cos(t - s) $$

Where $a, b, c \gt 0 $.

My effort:

Find the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $t$ and $s$ and equate them to zero:

$$f_t = - a \sin(t) - c \sin(t - s) = 0 $$

$$f_s = - b \sin(s) + c \sin(t - s) = 0 $$

It follows from these two equations that

$$ - a \sin(t) = b \sin(s) $$

Now,  $$\cos^2(t) = 1 - \sin^2(t) = 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \right)^2 $$

We now have:

$$ c \sin(t - s) = - a \sin(t) $$

Expanding the left hand side,

$$ c \bigg( \sin(t) \cos(s) - \cos(t) \sin(s) \bigg) = - a \sin(t) $$

Eliminate $\sin(t) $ and $\cos(t) $, and substitute for them in terms of $\sin(s)$:

$$ c \bigg( - \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \cos(s) - \sin(s) \left( \pm \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \right)^2} \right) \bigg) = b \sin(s) $$

This implies that either $ \sin(s) = 0 $, in which case $\sin(t) = 0 $ as well, and the value of the function in this case will be $ a + b + c $, which is obviously the maximum, or it is non-zero, and that

$$ c \bigg( - \dfrac{b}{a} \cos(s) \mp \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \right)^2 } \bigg) = b $$

So that

$$    \dfrac{b}{a} \cos(s) \pm \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \right)^2 } = -\dfrac{b}{c} $$

Re-arranging and squaring

$$ 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \sin(s) \right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{b}{c}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \cos(s) \right)^2 + 2 \left( \dfrac{b^2}{ac} \cos(s) \right) $$

And this simplifies to

$$ 1 - \left( \dfrac{b}{a} \right)^2 = \left( \dfrac{b}{c} \right)^2 +2 \left( \dfrac{b^2}{ac} \cos(s) \right) $$

Multiplying through by $ a^2 c^2 $

$$ a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 = a^2 b^2 + 2  a b^2 c \cos(s) $$

From which we have

$$ \cos(s) =  \dfrac{ a^2 c^2 - b^2 c^2 - a^2 b^2 }{ 2 a b^2 c } $$

And this can be written as

$$ \cos(s) = \dfrac{1}{2 b} \left( \dfrac{a c}{b} - \dfrac{bc}{a} - \dfrac{a b}{c} \right)$$

From symmetry of the function $f(t,s) $ this implies that

$$ \cos(t) = \dfrac{1}{2a} \left( \dfrac{b c}{a} - \dfrac{a c}{b} - \dfrac{ a b }{c} \right)$$

It follows that

$$ \sin^2(s)= \dfrac{1}{4 b^2} \left( - \dfrac{a^2 c^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{b^2 c^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{a^2 b^2}{c^2} + 2 a^2 + 2 b^2 + 2 c^2 \right) $$

And

$$ \sin^2(t) = \dfrac{1}{4 a^2} \left( - \dfrac{a^2 c^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{b^2 c^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{a^2 b^2}{c^2} + 2 a^2 + 2 b^2 + 2 c^2 \right) $$

We now have

$$ \cos(t - s) = \cos(t) \cos(s) + \sin(t) \sin(s) $$

$$ \cos(t) \cos(s) = \dfrac{1}{4 a b} \left( \left( \dfrac{a b}{c} \right)^2 - \left( \dfrac{a c}{b} \right)^2 - \left( \dfrac{b c}{a} \right)^2 + 2 c^2 \right) $$

$$ \sin(t) \sin(s) = -\dfrac{1}{4 a b} \left( 2 a^2 + 2 b^2 + 2 c^2 - \left( \dfrac{a c }{b} \right)^2 - \left( \dfrac{ b c }{a } \right)^2 - \left( \dfrac{a b }{c} \right)^2 \right)$$

Adding the two expressions

$$ \cos(t - s) = \dfrac{1}{2 a b} \left( - a^2 - b^2 + \left(\dfrac{a b }{c}\right)^2 \right) $$

Now $$f(t, s) = a \cos(t) + b \cos(s) + c \cos(t - s) $$

Substituting the above expressions for $\cos(t), \cos(s)$ and $\cos(t - s) $ gives us

$$ f^* = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{b c}{a} - \dfrac{a c}{b} - \dfrac{ a b }{c} \right) + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{a c}{b} - \dfrac{bc}{a} - \dfrac{a b}{c} \right) + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( - \dfrac{ a c }{b} - \dfrac{b c }{a} + \dfrac{a b }{c} \right) $$

And this reduces to

$$ f^* = - \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{ab}{c} + \dfrac{ac}{b} + \dfrac{bc}{a} \right) $$

So in conclusion, the maximum is $ a + b + c $ and the minimum is given by the expression for $f^*$.

My question is:  Are my findings correct ? Any helpful comments, suggestions, and answers are highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After a comment by Andrei, I found that a necessary condition for the formula for $f^*$ to work is that

$$ c \ge \dfrac{a b}{a + b} , \ a \ge \dfrac{b c}{b+c} , \ b \ge \dfrac{a c}{a + c} $$

Comment: Have you tried inputting this into a 3D calculator, like Geogebra?

Comment: No. I haven't, I not very familiar with Geogebra. @Mailbox

Comment: I did not look into details into your derivation. The maximum looks OK. But the minimum does not. Choose a very small $c$ value, so that the last term has no real impact. Then the minimum is going to be $-a-b$ when $\cos t=\cos s=-1$. In $f*$ the last two terms will become $0$, but the first term will diverge to $\infty$